# actionscript 3 gotoAndPlay parent play

Tags: flash, actionscript, parent

I am trying to create a Flash file Action Script 3 for playing two MOVIECLIPS with animation. Each MovieClip is on a single frame in its layer and two layers are one over other.My goal is to put code in each layer to play the next frame in next layer at the end of current layer animation.

Please help me if you have an example for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each movieclip add `stop();` script on the first keyframe and end of keyframe also. And in the action layer write `mc_1.gotoAndPlay(2);` and at `mc_1` in the  end of keyframe write `MovieClip(parent).mc_2.gotoAndPlay(2);`

Comment: you help me so much. i did a litel chnge    stop();
MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay(1);   thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
stop();
mc1.addFrameScript(mc1.totalFrames - 1, nextFrame);
mc1.gotoAndPlay(1);
mc2.stop(); //if mc2 is on same frame with mc1

function nextFrame():void{
this.gotoAndStop(2); //if mc1 & mc2 is on different frame;
mc2.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Add this to the 1st frame of the stage/mc that holds both the mc